# How do I find all of the parasites belonging to the particular pet of a particular user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Okay, I feel like I'm starting to come to SO for every activerecord query I have to write now and I'm starting to drag out my user/pet/parasite metaphor but here we go again.

In the following setup;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  has_many :parasites, :through => :pets
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parasites
  belongs_to :user
end

class Parasite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

I want to write a search that will return all of the parasites that belong to Bob's cat (i.e. User.name = 'Bob' and Pet.animal = 'Cat').

I realise I can do this with the fairly drawn out and ugly

```
User.where(:name => 'Bob').first.pets.where(:animal => 'Cat').first.parasites
```

but I thought there should be a more succinct way of doing this.

All of my attempts to write a join statement to make this happen result in an ActiveRecord::Configuration error so I suspect I am going about this backwards. Once again, this seems like it should be easier than it is.

Thanks.

Comment: important: rename `belongs_to :pets` (plural) into `belongs_to :pet` (singular) in your Parasite Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to achieve a `has_many through has_many` association. This won't work using Rail's eager loading associations.

What you have to do is:

- join the `users`
- join the `pets`
- scope `users` down by `username`
- scope `pets` down by `user_id` and the `animal` field

In ActiveRecord:

```
Parasite.joins(:pet).joins('INNER JOIN users').where('users.name = ? AND pets.user_id = users.id AND pets.animal = ?', @username, @animal)
```

Alternatively you can create a named scope:

```
class Parasite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet
  scope :parasites_of, lambda {|owner, animal_type| joins(:pet).joins('INNER JOIN users').where('users.name = ? AND pets.user_id = users.id AND pets.animal = ?', owner, animal_type) }
end
```

Now you can call `Parasite.parasites_of('Bob', 'Cat')`

The resulting SQL Query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM parasites
 INNER JOIN users,
 INNER JOIN pets ON pets.id = parasites.pet_id
WHERE
  users.name = 'Bob'
  AND
  pets.user_id = users.id
  AND
  pets.animal = 'Cat'
```

(Hint: The `.to_sql` method will show you the plain SQL query)

Comment: That's great, and I understand how it works, although I will still have to do another database search to find the id of user. Is there a way that lets me use the user's name directly (i.e. incorporate the search on the user table into the query).

Comment: I couldn't make your query work as you wrote it but it worked like this: Parasite.joins(:pet).joins('INNER JOIN users').where('users.name = ? AND pets.user_id = users.id AND pets.animal = ?', @username, @animal).